# Debugging FBPlacePickerViewController loaddata method

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to use [FBPlacePickerViewController loadData], and do some logic on the data received, before using the view.
How can I see the location information received in the loadData method?

Answer (score 0):

You may look into using the FBPlacePickerDelegate: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/protocol/FBPlacePickerDelegate

It's not quite clear what you want to do, but if you're looking to filter the places, you can check out the placePickerViewController:shouldIncludePlace: delegate method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
What I'm trying to do is more like decide on the order in which they are displayed, and changing the design of the list.
Do you know of a way to do that?

Comment: You can't do that with the current SDK. You may have make your own place picker as you wish to do more customizations. Just make a Graph API call and order the results as you wish. You can still use say the ProfilePictureView if you want to display a place's profile picture.